# Convert date string to date object in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a date string from a REST API in the format like this

`2021-01-29T17:15:46+1100`

and I need to convert it to an actual date so I can use the year, month, day, time and timezone as separate elements.

I am trying to use Python `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` but I keep getting the error

`ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-01-29T17:15:46+1100'`

I've done a lot of search on Google but everything I've come up with doesn't include using the +xxxx in the date.

The reason to convert is I need to store the date in a MySQL table datetime column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```py
import datetime
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-29T17:15:46+1100', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

This may help you.